# How can I move an image to be alongside text in HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying something out. I need the Meter (coloured bar) on the right and the text on the left. The problem is that the meter does not go above the text. See the image below for what I mean:

[image: Current page with the following code]

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link href = "stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <style>

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'fontbold';
        src: url('akzidenz-grotesk-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('akzidenz-grotesk-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'fontregular';
      src: url('akzidenz-grotesk-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('akzidenz-grotesk-light-webfont.woff') format('woff');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
    }
    h1 {
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 4em;
      color: #000000;
      margin-bottom: .3em;
      margin-left: 1em;
      font-family: fontbold;
    }
    h2 {
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 3em;
      color: #000000;
      margin-top: 1em;
      margin-left: 1.4em;
      font-family: fontregular;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <h1><br></br>TITLE</h1>
  <h2>john doe</h2>
  <img src="Meter.png" style="padding-left:95em">
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, the code's probably very messy - I'm just learning. I would love to know how my problem can be solved? (Moving the bar upwards, along the text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your own layout probably the easiest way to do this could be to add a float to the image. The thing is that you'd need to change the order of elements.

```html
<body>
  <img src="Meter.png" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em;">
  <h1><br></br>TITLE</h1>
  <h2>john doe</h2>
</body>
```

Here's an example of a similar structure with a snippet.

```html
<body>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="
float: right;
margin-left: 1rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
"><h2>Test title asd pgoasdkg opaskg paskdgpo askdgpo askdgpo kasdpogk asdpogkasdpod gkaposdk gpoasdkg paosdkgp oaskdgpoa ksdpog kaspodgk aspodgk aspod gkaspodgk aspodgk apsodkg paosdkgpoa sdkgpoa sdkgpasod kpaosdgk </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent volutpat volutpat nisi. Nam consequat nulla quis nisi fringilla, in iaculis augue accumsan. Maecenas tincidunt libero non bibendum ultrices. In volutpat ut elit non tristique. Fusce pellentesque viverra magna bibendum venenatis. Phasellus a porttitor neque. Pellentesque lectus diam, egestas at lacinia a, tristique quis tortor. Vivamus placerat arcu in hendrerit dapibus. Integer non risus vestibulum, pharetra ligula eu, tempor tellus.</p>

<p>In maximus odio mauris, semper eleifend tellus auctor a. Nunc suscipit consectetur felis, a accumsan velit fermentum vel. In laoreet tellus vitae risus scelerisque ultrices. Quisque pulvinar nulla quis lectus volutpat sodales. Duis sagittis odio dictum ligula blandit sollicitudin. Curabitur fermentum nunc eget eros tincidunt vulputate. Duis ullamcorper elit nec eros sollicitudin, nec ultrices mauris imperdiet. Donec ornare aliquam velit vitae accumsan.</p>

<p>Nullam a hendrerit velit. Vivamus vitae tortor sodales, finibus elit et, pretium massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras porta dolor quis sodales vehicula. Nulla nec consequat quam, ut interdum velit. Pellentesque consectetur, ipsum nec porttitor interdum, metus quam commodo justo, nec ornare lorem libero eget purus. Nunc nisi quam, lobortis vel eros in, elementum mollis erat. Etiam id ante cursus, bibendum metus lobortis, viverra ante.</p>

<p>Morbi ac lectus massa. Nunc elit nunc, lacinia ut mauris ut, euismod molestie magna. Maecenas id facilisis neque. Morbi sodales augue sit amet mattis blandit. Vivamus pharetra risus at nisi convallis, sed ornare nunc pharetra. Fusce molestie purus vitae quam sollicitudin, ac cursus felis vehicula. Vivamus eros dolor, condimentum sed blandit non, consequat vel nulla. Duis et augue mauris. In faucibus quis eros vel commodo. Mauris hendrerit mauris nibh, in aliquam leo laoreet nec. Pellentesque ornare sed urna at aliquam. Etiam consectetur lectus quis hendrerit fermentum.</p>

<p>Proin accumsan nisl sapien, nec venenatis felis aliquam et. Etiam accumsan varius neque, eu placerat nisl suscipit vel. Phasellus lacus dui, lacinia ac consectetur a, efficitur sed lacus. Phasellus rhoncus velit et quam varius, ac malesuada risus malesuada. Sed dignissim consectetur malesuada. Sed quis dictum nisi. Mauris venenatis sapien in accumsan vulputate. Integer interdum sed lacus nec pharetra. Sed tincidunt mi in sagittis hendrerit.</p>

</body>
```

You could play with both `float: right;` and `float: left;`. Normally the text adjusts to an image if there's a float on it.

**EDIT - Add some info based on your margin comment**

Yes, you can do the same with padding. The combinations are:

```css
margin: 2rem; // 2rem margin on all sides
margin: 2rem 3rem; // 2rem top and bottom, 3rem right and left
margin: 2rem 3rem 4rem; // 2rem top, 3 rem right and left, 4rem bottom
margin: 2rem 3rem 4rem 2.5rem; // 2rem top, 3rem right, 4rem bottom, 2.5rem left

It's something like this:
margin: all;
margin: top-bottom right-left;
margin: top right-left bottom;
margin: top right bottom left;
```

That's the order they are normally used in. Same thing works for padding.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise you can just use 'margin: w x y z'

Comment: @HenryHudson I added some more info on margins so that you can have a reference on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using flex. For the image to align at the right side of text, both of them should be in a same container. Use `justify-content` property of flex to make the items at start and end positions

```css
 h1 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-family: fontbold;
}
h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 1.4em;
  font-family: fontregular;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1><br></br>TITLE</h1>
    <h2>john doe</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444041103143-1d0586b9c0b8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width: 200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image won't align with text because `<h1>` and `<h2>` are block elements. You have to make them `display: inline-block;` to align image with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work for you. If it does not seems to work reduce the padding-left from 95em to your screen size.

```
<span>
   <h2 style="display:inline;">john doe</h2>
   <img src="Meter.png" style="padding-left:95em"/>
</span>
```

output will look like

[image]